# Java streaming Hashmap

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I want to convert my Hashmap for loop to Java8 streams. This is my code.

```
int amount = 100; 
Map<String, Account> map = accountMap;

for (Map.Entry<String, Account> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    String id = entry.getValue().getAccount_id();
    updateAccount(amount, id);
}
```

It will be something like this but couldn't figure exact syntax:

```
accountMap.entrySet().parallelStream()
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                            e -> e.getKey(),
                            e -> e.getValue()
                           //Where can I call external method?
                    ));
```

Comment: `map.values().forEach(v -> changeAmount(amount, v.getAccount_id())`? But I'd keep your for loop. Just, loop over the values instead of the entry set since you don't want the key.

Comment: @Tunaki thats a for each and not parallel stream?

Comment: @Tunaki I see, but I want to use paralelstreams to take advantage from multithreading

Comment: Well you can always have `values().parallelStream().forEach(...)`, but I'd measure first that it is actually faster. Also, make sure that `chargeAccount` can safely be used concurrently.

Comment: `accountMap.values().parallelStream().forEach(v -> this::chargeAmount(100, v.getAccount_id()));`

Comment: @eckes thanks, but I get many  errors for that code. Can you be sure its correct?

Comment: No I cant, you did not provide a compileable sample But the "this::" is wrong anyway you can remove it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you only are using the values get the values and create a stream from that.

```
  map.values().parallelStream()
              .forEach(value ->
                updateAccount(amount, value.getAccount_id()));
```